# Add buttons inside li in dynamically created listview in phonegap JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am ought to create an attendance application in phonegap...
I want that the list of students name have 2,3 buttons below their name in the listview...
there would be a ul in which there will be the li where the name will be shown...
i just can't figure how can that buttons be added in li ...!

There should be a listview in which the name is shown in li & just below the name there should be a tick button, cross button, and 2-3 more.. 
after thAT another name below this li with same thing...
Please help me that how can i make this thing by phonegap using html,css,javascript,jquery,mobile jquery...

if anyone can just write the code initially , it would be very helpful...

Thank you,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the buttons in a controlgroup:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
  <li>John Smith
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/oghya9jq/)**

Comment: Thanks this was the precise thing i was wanting...